# Сортировка по дате с учетом времени

Tags: mysql

Как в MySQL сделать сортировку до дате с учетом времени. Например, есть даты:

```
2022-02-26 22:00:49
2022-02-27 21:55:51
2022-02-28 21:55:52
...
2022-03-29 21:55:52
2022-03-30 21:55:54
2022-03-31 21:55:58
```

Мне нужно чтобы время при сортировке тоже учитывалось. И получился такой результат

```
2022-02-28 21:55:52
2022-03-31 21:55:58
```

Я делаю такой запрос, но `ORDER BY period` не работает

```
SELECT * date_format(var1.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS period, FROM my_table ORDER BY period
```

Пробовал использовать `CAST(date_format(var1.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS CHAR) AS period` но это тоже не сработало..

Comment: а обычная сортировка по `order by date` не работает, или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')) DESC
```